# How do I install CVXOPT for Python 2.7 on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cvxopt, cvxpy

Ultimately I am trying to install [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/install/) for Python 2.7. CVXPY has a few requirements including [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/install/). I have tried two approaches, installing from Gohlke's website, where he hosts Windows Binaries for Python Extensions: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and building from source myself.

When using the binaries provided from Gohlke, I get the following error when trying to import in python:

```
import cvxpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
...
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cvxpy\interface\cvxopt_interface\dense_matrix_interface.py", line 26, in <module>
import cvxopt
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have checked that the `base.pyd` file is present in `cvxopt/`

When building from source I followed the instructions from the site and when eventually building CVXOPT with `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32` I got the following error:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc/C/SuiteSparse/AMD/Include -Isrc/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\c\suitesparse\suitesparse_config\suitesparse_config.o
src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c: In function 'SuiteSparse_tic':
src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c:358:21: error: storage size of 't' isn't known
 struct timespec t ;
                 ^
src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c:359:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_gettime' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t) ;
 ^
src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c:359:20: error: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
 clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t) ;
                ^
src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c:359:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/C/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.c:358:21: warning: unused variable 't' [-Wunused-variable]
 struct timespec t ;
                 ^
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I did some research into this and `error: storage size of 't' isn't known` but i can't determine if it's CVXOPT's fault or Windows?

I'm using Python2.7 on Windows 10. Any suggestions or clarity on some of these issues would be great. Like I mentioned, just trying to get CVXPY working, but seem to be hung up on CVXOPT. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I was able to get a working installation of CVXOPT by uninstalling the current numpy version I had and downloading / installing the numpy-mkl whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. I then installed CVXOPT and CVXPY from the site as well. Finally was able to get a successful import cvxpy without the cvxopt.base DLL error.

Still would be curious about the compilation error I was having.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day using wheels from gohlke. Still curious why the numpy version in anaconda doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for this. My 2 cents on this:

With Anaconda on Windows 7 I just used the omnia repo `conda install -c omnia cvxopt`. It looks like it's working. Will update here if it breaks.